# What is the exact meaning of CAVOK and CAVU? How are they used by pilots and ATC?

Tags: air-traffic-control, weather

Do CAVOK (ceiling and visibility okay) and CAVU (ceiling and visibility unlimited) have formal definitions worldwide?

[image]
<sup>CAVOK, source: [formercaptain.ca](http://www.formercaptain.ca/category/arcadia-flies-again/)</sup>

Are they used in ATC communications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CAVOK is formally defined in ICAO Annex 3 ( APP3-2 2.2 Use of CAVOK ) . You can hear it at the airports where there is no ATIS , when ATC communicates the weather info.
CAVU is not formally defined in Annex 3 .

> When the following conditions occur simultaneously at the time of observation:
>
> ```
>  a) visibility, 10 km or more, and the lowest visibility is not reported;
>  b) no cloud of operational significance;
>  c) no weather of significance to aviation as given in 4.4.2.3 and 4.4.2.6;
> ```
>
> information on visibility, runway visual range, present weather and cloud amount, cloud type and height of cloud base shall be replaced in all meteorological reports by the term “**CAVOK**”.

Comment: Could you quote the actual definition from the document you refer to?

Comment: So what may be the difference between CAVOK and CAVU?

Comment: This answers 1/2 of the question (while CAVU isn't defined by ICAO, it still has a meaning...)

Answer (score 7):

[CAVU](https://www.fltplan.com/abbreviations.htm) means: "CLEAR OR SCATTERED **C**LOUDS **A**ND **V**ISIBILIY **U**NLIMITED (GREATER THAN TEN MILES)"

[CAVOK](https://www.fltplan.com/abbreviations.htm) means: "**C**LOUD **A**ND **V**ISIBILITY **OK** (METAR)."

[This military document](http://chesapeakesportpilot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/military_wx_codes.pdf), has a little more background:

> Overseas locations may use the contraction “CAVOK” (ceiling and
>   visibility OK). **CAVOK** is used when there is no **significant weather,
>   the visibility is 10 km or greater, and the ceilings are greater than
>   5,000 ft**.

I have never heard them used in verbal ATC communication, and they are **not** listed in the [Pilot/Controller Glossary](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_4-03-14.pdf) so should not be used on the radio.

Answer (score 2):

**Actual Definition From Annex 3**
When the following conditions occur simultaneously at the time of observation:
a) visibility, 10 km or more, and the lowest visibility is not reported;

*Note 1.— In local routine and special reports, visibility refers to the value(s) to be reported in accordance with
4.2.4.2 and 4.2.4.3; in METAR and SPECI, visibility refers to the value(s) to be reported in accordance with 4.2.4.4.
Note 2.— The lowest visibility is reported in accordance with 4.2.4.4 a).*

b) no cloud of operational significance;
c) no weather of significance to aviation as given in 4.4.2.3, 4.4.2.5 and 4.4.2.6; information on visibility, runway visual range, present weather and cloud amount, cloud type and height of cloud base shall
be replaced in all meteorological reports by the term “CAVOK”.